# If $ \vert z \vert = a $ then what is the real part of $ ( \frac{z-a}{z+a} ) $

Tags: complex-numbers

I am beginner to complex numbers.
I am having no idea to solve this:
Let $ z $ be any non - zero complex number.
If $ \vert z \vert = a $ , then what is the real part of $ ( \frac{z-a}{z+a} ) $ ?

"a" is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $Re(w) = \frac {w + \bar{w}} 2, w \in \mathbb{C}$ for $w=\frac{z-a}{z+a}$ then make the calculus.

You'll get something like: $\frac 1 2 (\frac{z-a}{z+a} + \frac{\bar{z}-a}{\bar{z}+a}) = \frac 1 2 (\frac {a^2 + za-a\bar{z} - a^2 + a^2 - za+a\bar{z} - a^2}{(z+a)(\bar{z} + a)}) = 0$

Comment: What is the conjugate of $ z $ ??

Comment: @MaanavRoy You are missing some basics, I can't help you.

Comment: Conjugate of $ z  = c + id $ is $ z' = c - id $ and $ z z' = \vert z \vert ^2 $

Answer (score 0):

Here's a geometric approach.  Note that $z$ is a point on the circle of radius $a$ centered at $0$, and $z-a$ and $z+a$ are the vectors from $a$ and $-a$ to $z$.  The points $z$, $a$, and $-a$ form a triangle with the segment from $a$ to $-a$ being a diameter of the circle.  Since $z$ is also on the circle, Thales' theorem says the angle at $z$ is a right angle: that is, the vectors $z-a$ and $z+a$ are perpendicular.  This means $\frac{z-a}{z+a}$ is purely imaginary, so its real part is $0$.

Answer (score -1):

WLOG $z=ae^{2it}$ where $t$ is real

$$\dfrac{z-a}{z+a}=\dfrac{e^{2it}-1}{e^{2it}+1}=\dfrac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{e^{it}+e^{-it}}=\dfrac{2i\sin t}{\cos t}=?$$